# Django view sometimes routes to wrong URL

Tags: python, django, leaflet, geodjango

I have a Django project with this layout

[image]

in the urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url as path
from mapping import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('map/', views.Map, name='map'),
    path('address',views.Address_Search,name='address')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse,HttpResponse
import geocoder
import pdb
bingkey='mykey'

def Map(request):
    return render(request,'mapping.html')

@csrf_exempt
def Address_Search(request):
    try:
        address=request.POST.get('fname')
        print(address)
        g = geocoder.bing(address,key=bingkey)
        x,y= g.latlng[1],g.latlng[0]
        print(x,y)
        return JsonResponse({'id': 1,'x': x, 'y': y,'Address': address})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return render(request,'mapping.html')
```

and in templates I have a mapping.html which contains

```
{% block content %}
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    <title>Sals Food</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {width: 100%;height:800px;}
        </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'search_bar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'turf/turf.min.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'basemaps/leaflet-providers.js' %}" > </script>

    <script>
        function subForm()
        {
          var jsdata = {"fname": $('#fname').val()};
          console.log(jsdata);
          var url = "/address/";
          var jqHdr = $.ajax({
                  async: true,
                  cache: false,
                  type: "POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: jsdata,
                  dataType: "json"
              }).done(function (data, textStatus) {
                  if (data.id == 1)
                  {
                      console.log("Longitude: "+data.x + " Latitude: "+data.y + " Address "+data.Address );
                      $('#map').remove();
                      var t = $("<div id='map'></div>");
                      $("body").append(t);
                      createmap(data.x,data.y,data.Address);
                    }
              });
          }

        function createmap(x,y,address){
            var map = L.map('map');
            map.setView([40.70,-73.90], 11);

            var boros = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("../static/boros.geojson",{
                onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.boro_name)
                }
            });       
            boros.addTo(map);

            L.marker([y, x]).addTo(map).bindPopup(address);
        
            lyrOSM = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.Mapnik');
            lyrESRIWSM = L.tileLayer.provider('Esri.WorldStreetMap');
            lyrESRITopo = L.tileLayer.provider('Esri.WorldTopoMap');
            lyrESRIImagery = L.tileLayer.provider('Esri.WorldImagery').addTo(map);

            objBaseMaps = {
                "Street - OSM":lyrOSM,
                "Street - ESRI":lyrESRIWSM,
                "Imagery - ESRI Imagery":lyrESRIImagery,
                "Topo - ESRI Topo":lyrESRITopo,
            };
            ctlLayers = L.control.layers(objBaseMaps,{}, {sortLayers:true}).addTo(map);
        }  
      </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="s01">
        <form action="/address/" method="post">
          <div class="inner-form">
            <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Enter a address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field third-wrap">
              <button class="btn-search" onclick="subForm()" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
 
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

**How it works**

The user enters in an address on the `http://localhost:8000/map/` like this
[image]

the entered address is put into a html POST request form and uses AJAX to pipe the POST request to the view.py Address_Search. The address is geocoded and it returns the x,y and address back to the page. For this example it works well as you can see the output is correct.
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKYU3.jpg
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

**Problem**

There are times where I enter in an address that's wrong or just random letters

for example I just entered in `55 water street` and this is what gets returned. It doesn't throw an error in the Address_Search view, it geocodes the input but for some reason it redirects to `http://localhost:8000/address/`  most of the time if the address is accurate this does not happen, thats why I am very confused. I must have something wrong here...

```
// 20210120180356
// http://localhost:8000/address/

{
  "id": 1,
  "x": -74.00910186767578,
  "y": 40.70320129394531,
  "Address": "55 water street"
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors printed in the shell where the server is running?

Comment: nope no errors -- when it does throw an error it will correctly render the mapping.html page back

Comment: Based on the return in the exception, I'm guessing the error is being thrown, and maybe just lost in the mix. Try changing the return on the exception to json instead of render, like in your `try`. Something like: `return JsonResponse({"error": "error"})` just to test it

Comment: I entered in `a fake address blah blah` and got this returned `// http://localhost:8000/address/

{
  "id": 1,
  "x": 9.539226531982422,
  "y": 11.746624946594238,
  "Address": "a fake address blah blah"
}`

Comment: and I changed what you recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an error on the address api somewhere. I would dig into that on the django side and see what's causing it. But, when that error is thrown, you're using `render`, which is going to render the html template you provide and let the page redirect. Since you're calling `/address/` and letting the page redirect, it's redirecting to that url.

You can change the response to a json response instead. I would change both the try and catch, and include a `status` key value pair as well as the data you want.

```
@csrf_exempt
def Address_Search(request):
    try:
        address=request.POST.get('fname')
        print(address)
        g = geocoder.bing(address,key=bingkey)
        x,y= g.latlng[1],g.latlng[0]
        print(x,y)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'data': {'id': 1,'x': x, 'y': y,'Address': address}})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error': e})
```

You could even clean it up a bit, specifically by using one JsonResponse:

```
@csrf_exempt
def Address_Search(request):
    response = {'status': None,
                'data': None,
                'error': None,
               }
    try:
        address=request.POST.get('fname')
        print(address)
        g = geocoder.bing(address,key=bingkey)
        x,y= g.latlng[1],g.latlng[0]
        print(x,y)
        response['status'] = 'success'
        response['data'] = {'id': 1,'x': x, 'y': y,'Address': address}

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response['status'] = 'error'
        response['error'] = e
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

*This might need some cleaning up as I'm just typing in SO, but that's the general idea*

edit - Also, this will result in some changes on the javascript side - you'll need to look for the status of error and deal with it, and get the data from the data value instead of just the returned object itself.

edit 2 - Make sure the form is not actually submitting when you press the button (it's being treated as a submit button even though you didn't explicitly say so). You can add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form itself, or at the end of your `done` method in jquery, add `return false;`

Comment: made your changes but I still have the same problem... entered `what is you problem` and it routes me to the address url like this `// http://localhost:8000/address/

{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 57.900001525878906,
    "y": 57.04999923706055,
    "Address": "what is your problem"
  },
  "error": null
}`

Comment: and then I went back to the page resubmitted and rendered the map url. I guess maybe its the geocoding API? or maybe its something with how I setup my django URLS and how it connects to the HTML POST form

Comment: What about: `return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response))`

You'll need to `import json` up top as well

Comment: made the change, on the JS side I had to JSON.parse it but its the same thing

Comment: I searched `this is a bad address` and it gave me back this `// http://localhost:8000/address/

"{\"status\": \"success\", \"data\": {\"id\": 1, \"x\": -18.578990936279297, \"y\": 64.98397827148438, \"Address\": \"this is a bad address\"}, \"error\": null}"`

Comment: then I click back, resubmit the same input and it maps it...im super lost

Comment: Are you seeing server output like this? https://imgur.com/a/kPL20ev I need to run for a bit but I'll come back to help later if no one gets to you first!

Comment: for the above example this is the server output `this is a bad address
-18.578990936279297 64.98397827148438
[20/Jan/2021 19:07:04] "POST /address/ HTTP/1.1" 200 161`

Comment: One thought I had last night that is not related to my answer (but I stand by the changes in my answer!) is to `return false` on `subForm` - it might be submitting the form and that's causing the redirect.

Comment: so something like this? `<form action="/address/" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">`

Comment: that seemed to work! I haven't seen what was happening before in like 50 tries. add that to your answer and ill accept. thank you!